# Router restarts when I upload something to internet

Tags: networking, upload, lede

I  have  a  LEDE router  used  behind  the  main router  as  a  antenna  for  my  desktop , and  when  I  try  to  upload  something to   internet   it restarts  but when  downloading  is  working well.What  could  be  the  problem  ? Could  somebody  help  ?

Router : TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v8
Firmware : LEDE Reboot 17.01.7 r4030-6028f00df0 / LuCI lede-17.01 branch (git-19.167.54478-71e2af4)

Status :
[Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udcCQ.png)

Comment: Isn't LEDE pretty old? Didn't LEDE get merged back into OpenWrt years ago? Maybe put the latest stable supported OpenWrt on your router and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using another ethernet cable. If not, replace ethernet cables. There could be a short in one of them.

In the future you would want to update your post with a model number so that people can better assist you. Also, you may want to include the model number of the ethernet card or motherboard model if it is integrated. Then you may want to include information from your computer system like operating system version and related command prompt information.

Here is a helpful tutorial on how to use the command prompt in Windows 10 to get information on your own network.
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-advanced-networking-commands/

Comment: LEDE is aftermarket firmware for routers. Routers don't have BIOS; that's an old term for a kind of firmware from the days of DOS PCs. I get the impression OP's knowledge of routers is decently advanced and you ended up on the wrong side of Dunning-Kruger on this one.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the ethernet cable because download works, and  I  think  with  not  my  pc because  it  worked  when  I  shared  internet  from  phone with  usb cable . The  version  of  my  router : TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v8 , Firmware : LEDE Reboot 17.01.7 r4030-6028f00df0 / LuCI lede-17.01 branch (git-19.167.54478-71e2af4)